# Extendable architecture to create subclass objects based on a string?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, unity-container

Consider a form where the user can upload a file.

I look at the mime type sent with the file (e.g. `application/pdf`) and want to construct an object of the appropiate type.

For PDF this would be an object of the `PdfDocument` inheriting from an abstract `Document` class.

How can I build this architecture to be easily extendable by additional "mime string to class" mappings? I want to make it easy to add classes for new mime types without having to change the existing code that handles the uploaded document.

The naive implementation would look something like this:

```
public Document GetDocumentByMimeType(string mimeType) {
    switch(mimeType)
        case "application/pdf":
             return new PdfDocument();
        case "application/msword":
             return new WordDocument();
        ...
}
```

I have to touch this code every time I want to add a new mimetype with a `Document` subclass.

I am using Unity as a IoC framework, can I solve this problem by registering the types somehow at startup? Is there maybe a way to register the types automatically just by adding the subclasses to the assembly?

And what would be the best way to resolve the class from the mimetype in the above method?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using `System.Activator.CreateInstance()`?

These methods allow you to create an instance of an object at runtime from the type or name of the class.

As such you can maintain a dictionary of classes or even have a database/config file loaded set which can then be used to create an instance of the required object.

For example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4.aspx),

```
ObjectHandle handle = Activator.CreateInstance("PersonInfo", "Person");
Person p = (Person) handle.Unwrap();
p.Name = "Samuel";
Console.WriteLine(p);
```

Creates an instance of `Person` from `PersonInfo` dll.

Answer (score 1):

If you are registering all the types of handlers by a particular interface or base class, then you can use a ResolveAll in the constructor of the class containing your method.

The following link describes the ResolveAll command

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660852(v=pandp.20).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660852%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx)

Have your handlers provide a key, which is the mime type supported by the class, then you can take the IEnumerable that is returned from the resolve all and turn it into a dictionary based on the key.

Finally in your method, just do a TryGetValue on the mime type against the dictionary and handle a missing mime type with a reasonable error message.

Comment: The dictionary would be some static property somewhere in my application set at program startup? Or would I inject it somehow into the method?

Comment: The dictionary would be a member of the class containing your method.  You could directly resolve it during the method, but then you'd be doing that multiple times. You could resolve it when the class receives the rest of the DI objects.